# Differential probability of modular subtraction $xdp^-$

Tags: differential-analysis, arx

The modular addition has been a main component in block  cipher. The use of modular subtraction in block cipher is not common but there are some cipher such as Bel-T cipher which uses both modular addition and subtraction.

To find the xor differential probability of modular addition, the following equation is used :

**$xdp^+ (\alpha,\beta,\gamma)= 2^{-\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}¬eq(\alpha[i],\beta[i],\gamma[i])}$**

$\begin{equation}
  eq(\alpha[i],\beta[i],\gamma[i])=\begin{cases}
    1, & \text{if $\alpha[i]=\beta[i]=\gamma[i]$}.\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}$

Iam interested to find the xor differential probability equation of modular subtraction $xdp^-$

Q: How to derive the $xdp^-$ equation? or  $xdp^+$ and $xdp^-$ are same

Comment: Define the operator $eq(.,.,.)$ and the symbols!

Comment: eq() is added , $\alpha$ , $\beta $ are input differences , $\lambda $ is output difference

Comment: Still unclear. What is the symbol in front of $eq()$? If its  a NOT how is it represented in the reals? Is there a modular inverse in the exponent?

Comment: Same as addition. Probability that $(a \oplus \alpha) - (b \oplus \beta) = (a - b) \oplus \gamma$ is the same as that of $(a \oplus \alpha) + (-b \oplus \beta) = (a + -b) \oplus \gamma$.